# How to deal with a Diesel generator (PDU6500E)?

Tags: electrical, generator, power-backup

Shortly after hurricane Sandy I installed a generator ([Powerland PDU6500E](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003BLPJF6)), which kept me and the rest of the county without a major power outage since.

With winter approaching yet again, I went to check the device and found, that it *would not start*:

- The starting battery is fine -- the "Battery Tender" and my volt-meter both say so (the actual voltage is shown as 12.30V).
- The control panel of the generator remains dark most of the time.
- When it lights up and I attempt to turn the key further to actually start, the machine coughs a little and the panel goes dark again.

The device sat outside for years -- covered and under the porch -- exposed to temperature changes, but not exposed to water.

I'm fairly certain, something is wrong with the panel... What are my options?

I wouldn't mind even paying a pro at this point, but have no idea, how to find one...

Comment: Did you turn the gas on?. A smart generator owner / installer shuts the gas off to save maintenance.

Comment: Take a reading of the battery voltage while you're cranking it over (turning the key to start it)

Comment: There is no "cranking" -- turning the key elicits no reaction. The panel is supposed to light up, when the key is in the "On" position, but does not -- or very briefly. (@EdBeal, the very title of the question says, the device is _Diesel_-powered, not gas-using...)

Comment: Check your battery under load or try a different battery

Comment: @EdBeal, the generator -- and I linked to the page describing it on purpose -- is a portable one. Its tank is inseparable from the rest, there is no (exterior) fuel-pipe, and no valve to turn on.

Comment: How do you change the fuel filter? I see a sales page but no maintenance info, looks likes problems with the batteries is common.

Comment: I haven't had to -- the total run-time of this device over the years is, probably, 10 hours. Or less. Yes, absence of actual documentation is a problem -- reflected in reviews too. But I doubt, my problem is with fuel-quality, I can not even get any sort of ignition going...

Comment: A portable generator is similar to a lawn mower engine. When I neglected to use mine for a few years and the fuel lines gummed up, a small engine repair shop fixed it for me for a reasonable price. But, it was a Honda generator, finding someone who will deal with your beast won't be as easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The battery is dead

Sandy was 2012 and 7 years is better than average for a starting battery. Given that this is emergency equipment, you really ought to replace it prophylactically well before that.

Basically the weak battery is acting like a capacitor.  That's why it shows voltage while and just after it's on the "battery tender".  Also 12.3 V is very low for a battery being maintained.

Before you attempt to start an engine with a weak battery, the battery shows normal because it has no load.  The starter presents a significant load and the thing instantly peters out.   That's normal for batteries.

You might try borrowing a car battery and see if that brings it back to life.  Other than that, if it requires competent repair, you may be out of luck - reviews show it is a Chinese cheapie, sold at a cut rate to what normal generators of that size should cost, and with virtually no support in the supply chain.

Comment: Yes, that's what it was...